# Binding Mode=TwoWay only working on "one" way

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm binding datas from a DbSet to a DataGrid thanks to an observable Collection. The way DbSet=>DataGrid works well, but the way DataGrid=>DbSet doesn't at all.

This is some codes to show you what I've done:

First of all, the Datagrid with the Binding properties:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DonneesBrutes" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.ResultatCollection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="10,65,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="PMRQ" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=.TOTMPMRQ, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="PMRQ"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="LibellePMRQ" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=.LibelléTOTApres, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Libellé PMRQ"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Ligne" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=.Remarque, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Ligne"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="OTM" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=.TOTMPMRQ, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="OTM"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="TOTM" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=.SiModifie, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="TOTM"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="LibelleTOTM" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=.LibelléTOTApres, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Libellé OTM"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="GA" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=.Groupe_D_alerte, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="GA"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Discipline" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=.NomTable, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Discipline"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DisciplineSubstituee" Width="120" Binding="{Binding Path=.NomChamp, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Discipline Substituée"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This is the ResultatCollection which is the ObservableCollection I made to bind datas from DbSet to DataGrid:

```
class ViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private BDDInterneEntities _BDDInterneEntities;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        _BDDInterneEntities = new BDDInterneEntities();
        ResultatCollection = new ObservableCollection<Resultat>(_BDDInterneEntities.Resultat);
    }         
    public ObservableCollection<Resultat> ResultatCollection { get; set; }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }

    }
}
```

And then this is what the DbSet Resultat looks like:

```
public partial class Resultat:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string NomTable { get; set; }
    public string Groupe_D_alerte { get; set; }
    public string NomChamp { get; set; }
    public string TOTMPMRQ { get; set; }
    public string SiModifie { get; set; }
    public string LibelléTOTAvant { get; set; }
    public string LibelléTOTApres { get; set; }
    public string Remarque { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }

    }
}
```

I have heard speaking about DataGrid.Items.refresh() but it sounds not working, DataGrid.ItemsSource = null    then    DataGrid.ItemsSource = myDataSource but it doesn't too.

I have heard too the mode=TwoWay and UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanges were enough, I'm quite lost.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Greetings.

Comment: Is that your actual implementation of `Resultat`? If so then you only technically implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` but ignored to actually raise the event if those properties change. (Same applies to `ViewModel`)

Comment: Yes, it is the actual implementation of `Resultat`. You mean I have implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged, but I haven't defined what it is supposed to do, is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to receive binding notifications you have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` correctly. The way you did it made it compilable, but not much else.

Every time a externally visible property changes you have to raise the `PropertyChanged` event. That's why you normally see code like

```
private int myProperty;

public int MyProperty
{
    get { return myProperty; }
    set
    {
        if (myProperty != value)
        {
            myProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you must not write directly to the field but use the property instead if you want to notify users of that class about property changes.

---

As you can see this gets quite tedious which is why several MVVM frameworks offer simplified versions, but you can also do your own version of it, for example

```
protected void Set<T>(ref T field, T newValue, string propertyName)
{
    if (field != newValue)
    {
        field = newValue;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }
}
```

Then your property would become

```
public int MyProperty
{
    get { return myProperty; }
    set { Set(ref myProperty, value, "MyProperty"); }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll assimilate what you told me and will adapt this to my code. If it works, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: I have a first question which is coming, I feel the if loop is only for one property, Am I supposed to do a loop for each string of Resultat or am I wrong?

Comment: If with *loop* you refer too the first codeblock in my answer then yes, you have to do that for every single public or protected property of your class.

Comment: just a last confirmation, Am I supposed to get something like this? `public string NomTable { get { return NomTable; } set { if (NomTable != value) { NomTable = value; OnPropertyChanged(""); } } }`

If yes, I don't understant what I'm supposed to write in the "", As it is a comparison between DbSet Datas and input from user in the DataGrid.. This code has been taken from `Resultat`

Comment: The string is the name of the property, in that case it should be "NomTable".